# Good Source for practicing discrete mathematics puzzles?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, soft-question, contest-math, book-recommendation

I am looking to practice questions like these:

[Problem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdRAU.png) (see text below)

[Problem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkQz6.png)

[Problem 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elOiN.png)

As you can see, these problems involve discrete mathematics, and are sort-of discrete mathematics puzzles. I want to practice more questions like these.

I know that there are multiple books on discrete mathematics, but I have observed that these problems don't test your theoretical knowledge much, but rather your problem-solving skills. Discrete Mathematics books, however, would focus more on the theoretical aspect.

I know that there is a book: [Algorithmic Puzzles by Anany and Maria Levitin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_Puzzles) which seems really good.

Can anyone recommend any other recommendations / books for such problems?

Kind Regards

Canopy

PS: I can not embed images so this is the gist of the first problem in case link doesn't work:

> A flexadecimal number consists of a sequence of digits, with the rule that the rightmost
> digit must be $0$ or $1$, the digit to the left of it is $0$, $1$, or $2$, the third digit (counting
> from the right) must be at most $3$, and so on. We write flexadecimal numbers in angle brackets to distinguish them
> from ordinary, decimal numbers. Thus $\langle 34101\rangle$ is a flexadecimal number, but $\langle231\rangle$ is
> not, because the digit $3$ is too big for its place. (If flexadecimal numbers get very long,
> we will need ‘digits’ with a value more than $9$.)
> Thus, the numbers $1$ to $13$ are
> represented as$1, 10, 11, 20, 21, 100, 101, 110, 111, 120, 121, 200, 201$ flexadecimal numbers.

> (i) Write the numbers from $5$ to $13$ in flexadecimal.

> (ii) Describe a workable procedure for converting flexadecimal numbers to decimal,
> and explain why it works.

> (iii) Describe a workable procedure for converting decimal numbers to flexadecimal.

> (iv) Describe a procedure for addition that works directly on the digits of two flexadecimal numbers,

> (v) Given a flexadecimal number, how could you test whether it is a multiple of $3$
> without converting it to decimal?

> (vi) If the $\langle100000\rangle$ arrangements of the letters abcdef are listed in alphabetical order and numbered $\langle0\rangle: abcdef , \langle1\rangle: abcdfe, \langle10\rangle: abcedf$, etc., what arrangement
> appears in position $\langle34101\rangle$ in the list?

Comment: Isn't flexadecimal just the [factorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system) (with the rightmost, redundant 0 removed)? Also, I think question 2(v) should first prove that $u$ actually exists.

Comment: Martin Gardner had a book called "Aha, Insight", years back. Can't remember what was in it.  Seems like logic puzzles and what not.  Maybe you'd like it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: The last three questions of the [Oxford MAT](https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/study-here/undergraduate-study/maths-admissions-test/mat-past-papers) get increasingly discrete, but you probably already know that since your three questions are excerpted from its 2019 edition.

Comment: @ryang Indeed, but, there are not many Past Papers for learning and practicing. Do you know any other sources?

Comment: The section on Combinatorics in http://www.mathpropress.com/mathBooks/ contains several references to books that might interest you.

Comment: @Arthur The problem asked seems to be a direct application of the factorial number system. Do you know any book where I can learn concepts like these? I have seen some books but they don't seem to cover these topics (like the factorial number system)...

Answer (score 1):

Try Project Euler (https://projecteuler.net/about). The problems there are not exclusively discrete, and some require programming, but you will definitely find at least a few discrete puzzles.

Answer (score 1):

These are all MAT questions from Oxford University. Go through all of the other past papers to do more like these. Questions 2, 5, 6 and 7 generally look most like the ones you have written above. STEP questions are also fun, and certain UKMT/BMO1 questions are good for this kind of thing too.